# Windows Server 2012 R2 DataCenter The request to list features available on the specified server failed

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, wifi, local-area-network

I am trying to add the Wireless LAN Service to my server but I first had to restart it because it installed some updates a while ago. After the restart it came up with the following error:

> The request to list features available on the specified server failed.

Server Manager:

[image]

Powershell:

[image]

What should I do now? I am not very experienced in Windows Server only in C# and some other programming languages.

Comment: Did you uh...try restarting it again? Windows has a funny way of sneaking in additional updates after a reboot.

Comment: If there's a pending update, or feature install, you cannot install another feature until it restarts.

Comment: @NathanC I already restarted it 3 times now.... and there are no pending updates.

Comment: Disregard my last comment, it was for another question... I apologize...

Comment: Please check the server manager - there should be a flag that tells you why the server wasn't able to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's a stuck pending reboot request.

Go to "C:\Windows\WinSxS" and check if there's a **pending.xml** file. Delete that file and try rebooting again. If you're unable to delete that file, try deleting it offline. If it's a virtual server, simply map its virtual disk somewhere and delete the file that way.

Answer (score 0):

Is it trying to add prerequisite features and restart first? I had a similar problem adding the WSUS role which was clashing when it also added the Windows Internal Database.

[This guy](https://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/2013/08/10/installing-wsus-on-windows-server-2012/) mentions the error, but my solution was different. Instead of changing group policy, I had to actually provide the WID account access to the WID directory:

```
$WIDService = "MSSQL$MICROSOFT##WID"
$Acl = Get-Acl "D:\WID\Data"
$Acl.SetAccessRule((New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($WIDService,"FullControl","Allow")))
Set-Acl "D:\WID\Data" $Acl
```

This isn't exactly your problem, but the symptom seems the same so it may lead you in the right direction at least.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the feature in powershell is named "wireless-networking", so the command would be "add-windowsfeature wireless-networking -restart"

Answer (score 0):

I have received similarly obtuse messages from Windows before, when trying to install a service that is not supported on Windows Server Core.

If you are running Core edition, then the Wireless LAN service is not supported on core.